# how to store gridView items click using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-sharedpreferences

I have a gridView of images and I've used CustomAdapter for populating the gridView. when user clicks on gridview items, the color of that itemchanges to white. user can just click on 2 items in gridView and change their color to white. when closing the application and again come back to the app, I want selected items stay in white color. I dont know how do this using shared preferences. any helps would be best appreciate.
below is my GridItem.java:

```
public class GridItem {
  private int imageId;

  public GridItem(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
  }

  public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
  }
  public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
  }
}
```

this is MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Integer[] images = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,
      R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f,
      R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h, R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j};

    final List<GridItem> gridItems;

    gridItems = new ArrayList<GridItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      GridItem item = new GridItem(images[i]);
      gridItems.add(item);
    }

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
      R.layout.grid_item, gridItems);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```

this is CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {
  Context context;
  int clickCounter  = 0;
  int sp_position = -1 ;

  public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<GridItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    this.sp_position = preferences.getInt("key",-1);

   // Log.e("sp","=>" + sp_position);
  }

  /*private view holder class*/
  private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
  }

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final GridItem gridItem = getItem(position);


    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(imageView);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
      final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;

      if(getItem(position).getImageId() == sp_position)
      {
        finalHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);
      }

      convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          clickCounter = clickCounter + 1;
          if(clickCounter <=2){
            finalHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.white);

              Log.e("position","=>"+position);

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("key", getItem(position).getImageId());
            editor.commit();
           // Log.e("LOG","=>" + getItem(position).getImageId());

          }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"You have selected 2 colors!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
        }
      });
    } else
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(gridItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;

  }
}
```

this is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is grid_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Start adding a boolean array to your adapter which indicates which items are white or selected. Then scroll to see if they remain their color. Once you have done that you can add code to save all booleans to shared preferences. And code to populate the array from shared preferences.

Comment: I'm new to android. would you please explain me more or write the code you said?

Comment: In onClick myarray[position] = ! myarray[position]. In getView if (myarray[position]) setwhite() else setnormalcolor();